# Polyline is not showing in Mapbox GL 4.2.2 SDK on device below GL version 3.0?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have integrated mapbox in my application. It is working properly in all other device which is having Open GL version 3.0 or above. However, in below 3.0 GL version device roads are not showing on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to this issue [6454](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6454) which we haven't been able to reproduce. Is this something you have been seeing only on 4.2.2 or does the issue occur on previous versions?

Comment: Previously I was using 0.7.4 version and and it was working properly but it was not gl map. Now I upgraded to 4.2.2 which is having gl map support and found this issue only with those device which is having GLES version 2.0